# Why does subclass run Superclass constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

When I run this code im just trying to populate a list with shift details and employees, I have premade an employee generator in the super class so i thought it would be good practice to not duplicate code. I am able to create the shift Array list and fill it but everytime I create the shift object it displays the `EmployeeSheet` fields.

heres the `EmployeeSheet` class :

```
import java.util.*;

public class EmployeeSheet
        extends Employee {
    private ArrayList<Employee> empSheet;
    private ProductionWorker pworker;
    private ShiftSupervisor sworker;

    /**
     * Constructs a list of randomly selected employees and displays the list.
     */
    public EmployeeSheet() {
        empSheet = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        Random empPicker = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            int id = empPicker.nextInt(20);
            if (id < 12) // roll for production worker
            {
                System.out.println("Adding Production Worker");
                empSheet.add(generateProductionWorker());
            } else //roll for Shift supervisor
            {
                System.out.println("Adding Shift supervisor");
                empSheet.add(generateShiftSupervisor());
            }
        }
        Iterator iterator = empSheet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(iterator.next());

        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates a Production Worker
     * @return The fields that make up a Production worker
     */

    public ProductionWorker generateProductionWorker() {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int numberOfEmployeeNames = Ename.length;
        ProductionWorker tempPworker = new ProductionWorker();

        String employeeName = Ename[rng.nextInt(numberOfEmployeeNames)];
        tempPworker.setEmployeeName(employeeName);

        int numberOfEmployeeNumbers = Empnum.length;
        String employeeNumber = Empnum[rng.nextInt(numberOfEmployeeNumbers)];
        tempPworker.setEmployeeNumber(employeeNumber);

        int yearHired = rng.nextInt(35) + 1980;
        tempPworker.setEmployeehireyear(yearHired);

        double weeklySalary = rng.nextInt((100) * 100);
        tempPworker.setEmployeeweeklyearning(weeklySalary);

        int hourlyRate = rng.nextInt(20) + 10;
        tempPworker.setHourlyRate(hourlyRate);

        pworker = tempPworker;

        return tempPworker;

    }

    /**
     * Generates a ShiftSupervisor employee
     * @return the Fields that make up a shift supervisor
     */

    public ShiftSupervisor generateShiftSupervisor() {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int numberOfEmployeeNames = Ename.length;
        ShiftSupervisor tempSworker = new ShiftSupervisor();

        String employeeName = Ename[ran.nextInt(numberOfEmployeeNames)];
        tempSworker.setEmployeeName(employeeName);

        int numberOfEmployeeNumbers = Empnum.length;

        String employeeNumber = Empnum[ran.nextInt(numberOfEmployeeNumbers)];
        tempSworker.setEmployeeNumber(employeeNumber);

        int yearHired = ran.nextInt(35) + 1900;
        tempSworker.setEmployeehireyear(yearHired);

        double weeklySalary = ran.nextInt((100) * 100);
        tempSworker.setEmployeeweeklyearning(weeklySalary);

        int goalsMet = ran.nextInt(100) + 1;
        tempSworker.setGoalsCleared(goalsMet);

        double yearlySalary = ran.nextInt((40000) + 40000);
        tempSworker.setYearlySalary(yearlySalary);

        sworker = tempSworker;

        return tempSworker;

    }

    public int checkSize() {
        return empSheet.size();
    }
}
```

Heres the shift class :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Shift
        extends EmployeeSheet {

    private ArrayList<Employee> shiftDetails;
    private ProductionWorker pWorker;
    private ShiftSupervisor sWorker;

    public Shift() {
        this.generateShift();

    }
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Shift
     */

    public void generateShift() {
        shiftDetails = new ArrayList();

        Random supervisorCount = new Random();
        int ssID = supervisorCount.nextInt(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < ssID; i++) {

            shiftDetails.add(this.generateShiftSupervisor());
        }

        Random productionCount = new Random();
        int prodID = productionCount.nextInt(15) + 5;
        for (int d = 0; d < prodID; d++) {

            shiftDetails.add(this.generateProductionWorker());
        }
    }

    public ProductionWorker generateProductionWorker() {
        pWorker = super.generateProductionWorker();
        return pWorker;
    }
    public ShiftSupervisor generateShiftSupervisor() {
        sWorker = super.generateShiftSupervisor();
        return sWorker;

    }

}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: An `ArrayList<Employee>` is a collection to which you can add an instance of class `Employee`, or an instance of any class that descends from `Employee`. If you add an `EmployeeSheet` to the List, it stays an `EmployeeSheet`. In other words the types of the objects in the List will be whatever class you said `new` of.  When you return the `tempPworker` and add it to the list, e.g., it will still be a `ProductionWorker` object.

Comment: Subclass runs superclass constructor because it is inherited, as every other protected or public method or attribute of the superclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any constructor you write in Java starts with an invocation to another constructor. If you don´t write it explicitly, then the compiler writes the following line for you as the first line of your constructor:

```
super();
```

That means that in order to construct any instance, you need to construct an instance of the parent class first (Except for the Object class that has no parent).

Think that this makes sense from the [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) perspective since when A inherits from B, it means that A "is a" B, with some particular state or behavior. In your case, it seems like you´re not using the inheritance for describing an "is a" relationship, which is probably a design error.

What I mean is that it doesn't seem that an EmployeeSheet "is a" Employee. You'd better model this relationship using only [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Comment: *Almost* any constructor. There is one exception: the constructor for `java.lang.Object.`

Answer (score 4):

> Why does subclass run Superclass constructor?

To construct the base object. Otherwise it would be unconstructed and the inheritance semantics would be incomplete.

> everytime I create the shift object it displays the EmployeeSheet fields.

Because the constructor for EmployeeSheet displays those fields.

> Any ideas why this is happening?

Because Shift extends EmployeeSheet.

Comment: Okay so back to the main problem,  how can I implement the method In the EmployeeSheet class so I can avoid duplicating code?

Comment: That's not the 'main problem', that's a brand new question.